# Rails Devise Invitable redirect after send invititaion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I got the devise invitable installed and working. Trying to figure out how to redirect the user after he/she sent an invitation out. Right now it's redirecting me to the root. I thought you can just set your custom path in the method below but it didn't work. Thanks in advance if anyone know where to customize the path after invite sent.

```
 def after_invite_path_for(resource)
    new_profile_path
  end
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I stumbled upon your question because I was having the same issue.  As far as I can tell the intended way for you to override after_invite_path_for is to override Devise::InvitationsController.

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def after_invite_path_for(resource)
    new_profile_path
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => "users/invitations" }
```

It would be nice if devise invitable worked like devise proper and you could override its after invite/accept paths in application controller.  I modified devise_invitable to work that way and submitted a pull request.  I'm not sure if it will be accepted or not, but you can have a look here: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/pull/240.

If that feature is accepted, you could patch your current version of invitable to respect definitions of after invite/accept paths in application controller by putting this in an initializer:

```
#make invitable's path functions overridable in application controller
[:after_invite_path_for, :after_accept_path_for].each do |method|
  Devise::InvitationsController.send(:remove_method, method) if ApplicationController.method_defined? method
end
```

Comment: I'm using devise_invitable with the patch above, but it still doesn't seem to work with an override in `ApplicationController`. Overriding `after_invite_path_for` in a `Users::InvitationsController` works, however the resource is incorrect. I asked the author to re-open the issue. https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/pull/240#issuecomment-11915891

Comment: the override worked for me, but the resource in params ended up being the current_user not the invited user. i was able to access the user by storing it off as an instance variable in the controller controller action, and then referencing that variable in the after_invite_path_for

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if its a good thing... or the worse to do however you can put:

```
  def after_invite_path_for(resource)
    new_profile_path
  end
```

in your application controller... seems to work OK!

Comment: works. confirmed. and you don't have to edit routes and create the invitations_controller.