# How do I change the redirect path after invitation is sent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

I am using Devise Invitable, and I found a few answers on SO ([here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720612/rails-devise-invitable-redirect-after-send-invititaion)) that say that I should specify the action `after_invite_path_for(resource)` in my `Users::InvitationsController < DeviseController`.

I tried that and it still doesn't work.

This is my controller:

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController

   def after_invite_path_for(resource)
     root_path
   end

   def create
      @member ||= Member.find_or_create_by(email: params[:user][:email], first_name: get_first_name(params[:user][:full_name]), last_name: get_last_name(params[:user][:full_name]), bio: params[:user][:bio], gender: params[:user][:gender])
      @membership ||= Membership.find_or_create_by(member: @member, family_tree: current_user.family_tree, inviter: current_user, relation: params[:user][:invitation_relation])

      if @user_exists ||= invited_user_exists(params[:email])

      else
        super
      end

    end
end
```

When I try to just add a `redirect_to root_path` right after the `super` in the `else` block....it throws an error about redirect is already called.

I believe that's true, because if you check the source of the [create action here](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb#L26) you will see the redirect.

This is the server log:

```
Started POST "/users/invitation" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-02 03:58:57 -0500
Processing by Users::InvitationsController#create as HTML
  Rendered users/mailer/invitation_instructions.html.erb within layouts/mail (1.2ms)

  # truncated for brevity

  Rendered users/invitations/create.html.erb within layouts/devise (0.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1424.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9221ms (Views: 4732.1ms | ActiveRecord: 102.0ms)
```

Note that it never redirects anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Devise Invitable redirect after send invititaion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720612/rails-devise-invitable-redirect-after-send-invititaion)

Comment: @PardeepDhingra It is that question and answer that I reference in my question. The whole premise of my question is based on the fact that the other one doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. For whatever reason, doing `after_invite_path_for(resource)` in my `Users::InvitationsController` wasn't overriding the `create` action in the `DeviseInvitable#Create`.

So, what I did was just use most of the logic from the official create action and just changed the redirect locally.

So now, my create action in my controller looks like this:

```
def create
  @member ||= Member.find_or_create_by(email: params[:user][:email], first_name: get_first_name(params[:user][:full_name]), last_name: get_last_name(params[:user][:full_name]), bio: params[:user][:bio], gender: params[:user][:gender])
  @membership ||= Membership.find_or_create_by(member: @member, family_tree: current_user.family_tree, inviter: current_user, relation: params[:user][:invitation_relation])

  if @user_exists ||= invited_user_exists(params[:email])

  else
    self.resource = invite_resource
    resource_invited = resource.errors.empty?

    yield resource if block_given?

    if resource_invited
      if is_flashing_format? && self.resource.invitation_sent_at
        set_flash_message :notice, :send_instructions, :email => self.resource.email
      end
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Invitation Successfully Sent."
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }
    end
  end

end
```

That works. It isn't Devise idiomatic...but it works for what I need.